# How to add FreeBSD 13 to Grub 2 boot loader

Tags: freebsd, grub2

I have Windows 10, Ubuntu 21.04 and FreeBSD 13 (UFS) installed on my SSD.
I'm able to load Windows 10 or Ubuntu via GRUB 2.04. However, I cannot make FreeBSD load from the GRUB menu. I've tried different configurations.

Secure boot is disabled:
[image]

My partitions:

- hd3,gpt3 - EFS
- hd3,gpt7 - FreeBSD's UFS2
- hd3,gpt9 - FreeBSD's swap

[image]

Some of the configurations I've tried:

```
set root=(hd3,gpt3)
chainloader /efi/freebsd/loader.efi
```

-does nothing. `chainloader` just returns without any message or action.

```
insmod ufs2
set root=(hd3,gpt7)
kfreebsd /boot/kernel/kernel
kfreebsd_loadenv /boot/device.hints
set kFreeBSD.vfs.root.mountfrom=ufs:/dev/nvme0n1p7
set kFreeBSD.vfs.root.mountfrom.options=rw
set kFreeBSD.hw.psm.synaptics_support=1
```

-returns error like "cannot find file /boot/kernel/kernel".

I've tried to list the directories in the path `/boot/kernel/kernel`, but with no success. I don't understand why. `ls $root` shows the description of the partition. However, `ls /boot` doesn't display anything except error like "directory not found".

I'm sure my FreeBSD partition is ok. I was able to work with it right after setup. I did reinstall FreeBSD just in case, but it didn't help.

Please advise.

**UPD**

Applied `set debug=all`.
Ran `chainloader /efi/freebsd/loader.efi`.
Got error "kernel signature verification failed".
[image]
`set check_signatures=no` doesn't make difference.

I'm trying to investigate how to fix it.

Comment: Your chainloader entry needs this: `insmod ufs2  `

Comment: @oldfred it doesn't make difference.

Comment: @oldfred kernel signature verification failed.

Comment: Is then UEFI Secure Boot on? If dual booting with Windows, it may do an UEFI update and reset to defaults. Check any UEFI settings you normally change. I keep a list as every UEFI update I have to redo several. But I do my own updates, so I know when I have to redo them.

Comment: @oldfred No, secure boot is disabled.

Comment: It then should not be asking for signed boot files & kernels.

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: @Rob could you tell me how to write output into a file working in the GRUB 2 shell? Besides, I dubbed with text the essential lines of all the photos. The photos 1) serve as a proof my words; 2) demonstrate extra bits of information (I might miss something crucial in the output). What I will not do is manually typing the output. Having these photos is better than not having them at all. I am trying to provide people as much information as I can.

Comment: [Do not post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: @Rob look at the note you reference to: `One other notable valid reason is that a camera snapshot or VM window snapshot is often the only way of posting BIOS, boot-loader, or kernel error messages`. GRUB 2 is a boot-loader

Comment: If you can connect to the serial console, I'm pretty sure you can get GRUB to use that to copy the boot loader output.  Assuming you have another machine and suitable serial cable, of course.

Comment: Update: I could not solve the issue and gave up. Maybe one day someone give me a tip.